# Firebase description is corporate biased & not insightful

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

"Helps developers build better apps and grow successful businesses" is marketing-speak with zero functionality description.

Compare to other firebase tags. Despite their marketing-speak I can still interpret something functional about the topic:

[image: firebase]

Comment: For reference: [[tag:firebase]] [excerpt history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10392242/revisions)

Comment: Changed it to: *Firebase is an open-source platform for unified development of applications for mobile devices and for the Web*

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, thanks, now we may want to invite Doug Stevenson to answer this question.

Comment: I dont see there is anything wrong with the description.. lots of tags say that, [x] is used to build a website, and web services. [y] is used to create an application..

Comment: What question - I'm not sure what's been asked? Tag wiki's are awesome because you can edit them to make them more useful. :)

Comment: Both marketspeak wiki contributors/editors (there have been two separate incursions) were according to profiles Google Firebase employees (engineer & "advocate"). (The first editor was too.)

Comment: @Peter well then we have more tags to update. It's better to have no description at all than _"[x] is used to build a website"_. I mean with enough effort, _anything_ can be used to build a website.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I'm afraid Firebase is not open-source. Here's [my suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18654309)

Comment: Note that this is a sponsored tag. The company might feel a bit entitled to play up their product description because they pay money for it. I don't know if there is precedent for this privilege, though. Typically sponsorship just gives an icon and the association of some links.

Comment: "Firebase is an open-source mobile and web app platform operated by Google, providing cloud services and authentication."

Comment: @TylerH Even if they feel entitled to, they're fools to do it. Programmers - who are the demographic you're reaching when you put content into a Stack Overflow tag wiki - stereotypically respond negatively to fluffy marketing bullshit, and as evidenced by the upvotes on this thread, that stereotype is rooted in reality. The employee who made this edit should have recognised that it would be considered objectionable and fought back against whoever asked them to make it - I would've thought that that's part of what a "Google Developer Advocate" is being paid for.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't read the question due to the crazy greenscreen colour scheme :)

Comment: @PeterHaddad the thing that's wrong is that it links a platform (Firebase) to a business outcome (your business succeeding and growing) that is not in any way guaranteed. It's no less absurd than if the Python tag wiki read *"Python is a general-purpose programming language that makes your boss pay you huge bonuses"*. This is the classic style of emotive and unfalsifiable marketing spiel - our product will make you rich! our product will make you happy! our product will make women want you! - and it's *crass*, and it doesn't belong in a technical description of a tag.

Comment: ***Lacks usage guidance*** (throughout)

Comment: @MarkAmery I definitely agree, just trying to provide a little insight into the potential reasoning, as programmers are also stereotypically bad with people and so they may not understand why marketers or businessfolk would make the choices they do.

Comment: Slightly OT but is there any way to get direct support from Google staff relating to Firebase & Adsense? I had numerous problems with their web interfaces, support told me to post on forums, forums re-directed me to support page where you need to earn money before you can get paid.. but I couldn't earn money because of API & website issues.

Answer (score 19):

This highlights a problem, but *probably* not the one you thought it might. Folks sometimes grab the "elevator pitch" right from the project site (usually word for word) and just paste it in. This happens for a few reasons:

- Someone working on a project is asked by their marketing department to update copy in various places, and they don't realize that it smells a little bad.
- Someone is looking to get some edits in, notices a blank info page for a tag being used, and just copies the elevator pitch from the project site word for word without attribution (rarely *with*) -- this is quite common.
- Someone is working with us and pays to sponsor a tag and doesn't understand the info page is supposed to be in the *community* voice, not the company voice. This one is rare, because usually by the time a company is looking to sponsor a tag, the tag and wiki / info page / etc have long since been created organically.

If you see overly market-y double-speak-y buzzword-bingo-ish-y gobbledygook - ***just edit it if you can***, or bring it here to meta if it smells off but you're not quite sure what to do with it. But, ***seldom*** is there actual malice at play, [TylerH was hinting at this with his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362628/firebase-description-is-corporate-biased-not-insightful#comment553289_362628):

> ... just trying to provide a little insight into the potential reasoning, as programmers are also stereotypically bad with people and so they may not understand why marketers or businessfolk would make the choices they do.

It's usually just a case of not quite understanding the differences in voice, and where each kind of voice (or perspective) is appropriate.

If someone pushes back on an edit just remind them that while tags can be sponsored if the company chooses to do so, the *voice* of the info and wiki pages (e.g. the voice we want folks to hear as they read) is the voice of the SO community, *not* the company, which is why we only offer brand reinforcement visually through the logo on the tag.

When pointed out, it's usually a "Oh, duh, sorry about that!" sort of moment.

Comment: "But, seldom is there actual malice at play" Hanlon's razor?

Comment: I have to agree with this perspective. Taking a quick look at Firebase's website, it looks like someone paraphrased (or used an older version) of the copy on there, which means this wasn't specifically written to beguile the SO audience....but i have to admit...as someone who has used Firebase for years now, that description could be talking about anything and does sound like BS.